# 0..1, 1..1 relationship with EF6 (fluent)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, fluent

I have these two models:

```
public partial class Account
{
    public Account() {}

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    // ...

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public Customer() {}
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid AccountId { get; set; }

    // ...

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

How can I set (using fluent) the optional Customer entity on Account without having a nullable CustomerId in it?

** AccountId on Customer table is an unique key.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something along this lines:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>() 
            .HasKey(t => t.Id); 


modelBuilder.Entity<Account>() 
            .HasOptional(t => t.Customer) 
            .WithRequired(t => t.Account);
```

And please make the  Ids not nullable. Primary keys are not supposed to be null by design.

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#RequiredToOptional

Comment: Did not work. Account.Customer is always null, even when it should not. When I use HasMany (changing Account.Customer to ICollection<Customer>), instead of HasOptional, it works. But it's not the way I want it to work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Solved removing AccountId from Customer and using its Id as the foreign key for the respective Account.

Answer (score 0):

Setup your models like this:

```
public class Account
{
    [Key]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public long AccountID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AccountID")]
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

Then connect the models like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.Customer)
    .WithRequired(x => x.Account);
```

**Notice how the Customer primary key is also a foreign key.** This is because your entity relationship diagram looks like this:

[image: Entity Relationship Diagram]

The Customer entity is a [*weak entity* (link)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_entity) that is dependent on the (strong) Account entity.